# retrieving post values from form with dynamic element names

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I'm trying to retrieve the post values from a form where the element names are based on values from a recordset.  Here is the form:

```
$recordID = $_GET["recordID"];
$colour_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT colour_variation.*, colours.* FROM colour_variation INNER JOIN colours ON colour_variation.colour_id=colours.colour_id WHERE product_code='$recordID'");
while($colour_row = mysqli_fetch_array($colour_result))
  {
 ?> 
<tr><td valign="middle"><img src="resources/images/colours/<?php echo $colour_row['colour_image']; ?>" width="35" height="35"></td><td width="100"><?php echo $colour_row['colour_name']; ?></td>
    <td><center><?php if($colour_row['xs'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="xs_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>" id="xs_<?php echo $row[colour_name]; ?>" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php if($colour_row['s'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="s_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>" id="s_<?php echo $row[colour_name]; ?>" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php if($colour_row['m'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="m_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>" id="m_<?php echo $row[colour_name]; ?>" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php if($colour_row['l'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="l_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>" id="l_<?php echo $row[colour_name]; ?>" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php if($colour_row['xl'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="xl_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>" id="xl_<?php echo $row[colour_name]; ?>" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php if($colour_row['xxl'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="xxl_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>" id="xxl_<?php echo $row[colour_name]; ?>" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php if($colour_row['xxxl'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="xxxl_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>" id="xxxl_<?php echo $row[colour_name]; ?>" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php if($colour_row['one_size'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="one_size_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>" id="one_size_<?php echo $row[colour_name]; ?>" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="<?php echo $row_products['product_code']; ?>" >
```

I tried this to get them out but its not working:

```
<?php 
$product_code=$_POST["product_code"];
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 2) == "xs_") {
            $colour_name[str_replace("xs_", "", $key)] = $value;
        }
        echo $key;
        echo '<br />';
        echo $value;
    }


?>
```

there could be any number of colours per product.  Any help on getting the values to display on next page with the qty selected per colour/size would be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: `WHERE product_code='$recordID'"` is dangerous, escape you sql data.

Comment: Problem is your PHP generating your input fields... you've got echo in echo, that won't work and you can probably see it when checking your HTML source. The names are probably  no correct. Your code to parse the posted values looks ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would change

```
name="s_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>"
```

etc to

```
name="attributes[s_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>]"
```

And use the following PHP

```
if( !empty($_POST['attributes']) ) {
    foreach( $_POST['attributes'] as $sKey => $iQty ) {
        var_dump( $sKey );
        var_dump( $iQty );
    }
} else {
    die( 'Just for debuging. attributes-array was empty' );
}
```

Or even better

use

```
name="attributes[xxl][color]" eg. name="attributes[xxl][<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>]"
```

And

```
if( !empty($_POST['attributes']) ) {
    foreach( $_POST['attributes'] as $sSize => $aData ) {
        var_dump( $sSize );
        var_dump( $aData );
    }
}
```

Comment: I was writting an answer but yours is better. +1

Comment: thanks to everyone for the quick replies.
when i try the above i get this :
string(1) "s" array(1) { [" string(1) "3" } string(1) "m" array(1) { [" string(0) "" } string(1) "l" array(1) { [" string(1) "3" } string(2) "xl" array(1) { [" string(0) "" } string(3) "xxl" array(1) { [" string(0) "" } string(2) "xs" array(1) { [" string(0) "" }

how can i get it to display the names of the fields?
again thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you run `var_dump( $_POST['attributes'] )` and post the result?

Answer (score 0):

You put PHP code inside a string, it does not get parsed by PHP that way:

```
echo '<input name="xs_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>">';
```

This should probably be concatenated like so:

```
echo '<input name="xs_' . $colour_row[colour_name] . '">';
```

The same goes for

```
echo '<input id="xs_<?php echo $row[colour_name]; ?>">';
```

Which needs to be converted to:

```
echo '<input id="xs_' . $row[colour_name] . '">';
```

Also is it possible that "$row" has to be "$colour_row" in the id attribute of the input field?

There are some other obvious improvements to be made, but those are outside the scope of your question.

---

I was closing my Netbeans and found this still sitting there, I hope it's of use ( not 100% guaranteed to work out-of-the-box ):

The form php would become:

```
<?php
$recordID = $_GET["recordID"];

// I adjusted the query somewhat.
// The colours tabel is joined with a USING() command
// The recordId is escaped
$colour_result = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT colour_variation.*, colours.*
    FROM colour_variation INNER JOIN colours USING(colour_id)
    WHERE product_code = '". mysqli_escape_string($con, $recordID)."'
");

// I'm using an alternative syntax for the while control structure ( I am
// using a colon instead of braces ):
while ($colour_row = mysqli_fetch_array($colour_result)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle"><img src="resources/images/colours/<?php echo $colour_row['colour_image']; ?>" width="35" height="35"></td>
        <td width="100"><?php echo $colour_row['colour_name']; ?></td>
        <!-- I'm using an alternative syntax for the if control structures here -->
        <!-- I also left out the else, since it did not print anything -->
        <!-- I used an array for the name notation, to easily read out the data -->
        <td><center><?php if ($colour_row['xs'] !== ''): ?><input type="text" size="2" name="quantity[<?php echo $colour_row['colour_name']; ?>][xs]" placeholder="Qty"><?php endif; ?> </center></td>
        <td><center><?php if ($colour_row['s'] !== ''): ?><input type="text" size="2" name="quantity[<?php echo $colour_row['colour_name']; ?>][s]" placeholder="Qty"><?php endif; ?> </center></td>
        <td><center><?php if ($colour_row['m'] !== ''): ?><input type="text" size="2" name="quantity[<?php echo $colour_row['colour_name']; ?>][m]" placeholder="Qty"><?php endif; ?> </center></td>
        <td><center><?php if ($colour_row['l'] !== ''): ?><input type="text" size="2" name="quantity[<?php echo $colour_row['colour_name']; ?>][l]" placeholder="Qty"><?php endif; ?> </center></td>
        <td><center><?php if ($colour_row['xl'] !== ''): ?><input type="text" size="2" name="quantity[<?php echo $colour_row['colour_name']; ?>][xl]" placeholder="Qty"><?php endif; ?> </center></td>
        <td><center><?php if ($colour_row['xxl'] !== ''): ?><input type="text" size="2" name="quantity[<?php echo $colour_row['colour_name']; ?>][xxl]" placeholder="Qty"><?php endif; ?> </center></td>
        <td><center><?php if ($colour_row['xxxl'] !== ''): ?><input type="text" size="2" name="quantity[<?php echo $colour_row['colour_name']; ?>][xxxl]" placeholder="Qty"><?php endif; ?> </center></td>
        <td><center><?php if ($colour_row['one_size'] !== ''): ?><input type="text" size="2" name="quantity[<?php echo $colour_row['colour_name']; ?>][one_size]" placeholder="Qty"><?php endif; ?> </center></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="<?php echo $colour_row_products['product_code']; ?>" >
```

The receiving end would be something like this:

```
<?php

    $iProductCode = $_POST['product_code'];

    foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $sColor => $aColourQuantityData) {
        foreach($aColourQuantityData as $sSize => $iQuantity) {
            echo "Product #$iProductCode, colour $sColor, size $sSize: $iQuantity pieces<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: He doesn't need to as of he is using the end bracket "?>". Would be more beautiful though.

Comment: @niclas-larsson: He does! But then later he uses: `<?php if($colour_row['xs'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="xs_<?php echo $colour_row[colour_name]; ?>" id="xs_<?php echo $row[colour_name]; ?>" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?>`. There's an echo in there and within that another <?php ?> pair. Which doesn't get parsed.

Comment: i now have it like :     <td><center><?php if($colour_row['xxl'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="xxl_' . $colour_row['colour_name'] . '" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>

the names now show correctly in the view source, however still getting problems retrieving values on next page.
BTW He is a She lol :)

Comment: Terribly sorry! I should have known by the Ms in MsKazza... ! Would you mind editing your question to reflect your changes? So we can help you from there?

Comment: I updated my answer with a suggestion to how to alter the form. This is not THE way to do this mind you, there's lots more to improve on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i now have it displaying as a list on the second page using the following code :

```
<td><center><?php if($colour_row['xxl'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="xxl_' . $colour_row['colour_name'] . '" placeholder="Qty">');
 } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>
```

and then :

```
<?php 
$product_code=$_POST["product_code"];

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
  echo "$key=$value";
  echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

on the second page.

thank you all for your help, your suggestions put me on the right track, much appreciated.