# PHP Retrieve Values from Dynamically Named Form Input Fields

Tags: php, forms

I've setup a form with a table which includes rows from a database. I've used a variable to represent the database record ID as the `name` for one of the rows like this:

```
<td><input type="text" name= "<?php echo $recordID; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="User Notes"></td>
```

which is working fine and ends up appearing like this in the browser:

```
<td><input type="text" name= "TSL1406" class="form-control" placeholder="User Notes"></td>
```

I'm having trouble retrieving the value when the form is submitted. I would normally use something like this:

```
$input = $_POST['userNotes']
```

which I've updated to handle the dynamic naming of the inputs like this:

```
$input = $_POST['.$recordID.'];
```

but this is returning an empty variable and I can't work out the correct syntax to retrieve the input from the $_POST array with a dynamically named input field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975624/retrieving-post-values-from-form-with-dynamic-element-names <-- check this you should find a clue here.

Answer (score 1):

single quote " ' " means literal, it won't display your variable name just literally `.$recordID.`. Try using double quotation instead.

```
$input = $_POST[".$recordID."];
```

Comment: That didn't work but this did: `$input = $_POST["$recordID"];` - i.e. remove the period between the double quote and the variable name

Answer (score 1):

Only `$input = $_POST[$recordID];` without quotes?

or you use arrays like:

```
<input type="text" name= "form[<?php echo $recordID; ?>]" class="form-control" placeholder="User Notes"></td>
```

and save everything at once

```
$input = $_POST['form'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just simply use  $_POST[$recordID]? However there is a better way to get `POST` variable using `filter_input(INPUT_POST, $recordID)`